# Query with Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that consists of 12 columns as follows:

```
acct, addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4, addr5, 
addr6, addr7, add8, zip, domicile, shares
```

What I need is to roll up the total `shares` into one row for duplicate rows. The criteria is that `addr1` through `addr4` are identical which determines that the row is a duplicate.

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
SELECT acct, addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4, addr5, 
addr6, addr7, add8, 
       zip, DOMICILE, sum(shares) as total_shares 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4 ORDER BY addr1;
```

Comment: Show sample data and desired results. Nobody wants to reverse engineer your query that "didn't work" and try to figure out what you meant for it to do.

Comment: What if two otherwise separate people live at the same postal address?

Comment: You're absolutely right Aaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting columns that aren't in your `GROUP BY` clause. You'll have to do some modification to them to get them into the result set, usually with either `MIN` or `MAX`, such as:

```
SELECT MIN(acct) as acct, na1, na2, na3, na4, MIN(na5) as na5, MIN(na6) as na6, MIN(na7) as na7, MIN(na8) as na8, MIN(zip) as zip, MIN(DOMICILE) as DOMICILE, sum(shares) as total_shares
FROM table_name
GROUP BY na1, na2, na3, na4
ORDER BY na1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some table gropuping logic like INTERSECT or EXCEPT

You could combine the diferent columns as you wish...

In this example I will catch all the cases where (addr1 = addr2 = addr3 = addr4)

```
SELECT acct, addr1 FROM table_name 
INTERSECT
SELECT acct, addr2 FROM table_name 
INTERSECT
SELECT acct, addr3 FROM table_name 
INTERSECT
SELECT acct, addr4 FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(total_shares)
from 
(
  SELECT na1, na2, na3, na4, sum(shares) as total_shares 
    FROM table_name 
   GROUP BY na1, na2, na3, na4 
  having count(*) > 1
) ttl
```